# Finding eccentricity, directrix, foci of diagonal ellipse by rotating it

Tags: conic-sections, rotations

A problem I'm working on has the equation for a diagonal ellipse

$$5x^2 + 5y^2 - 6xy - 8 = 0$$

which can be rotated 45 degrees to get the vertical ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{1}+\frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1$$

The problem is to find the eccentricity, directrices and foci of the diagonal ellipse, and I assume that since it made me perform this rotation, I'm supposed to utilize this new one.

I was able to find the eccentricity, directrices and foci of this vertical one, but I can't figure out how to use this to find the same attributes for the original, diagonal ellipse.

Comment: If you rotate an ellipse, why should any of those properties change?  It is, after all, the same ellipse; it's just rotated.

Comment: I can understand that the eccentricity doesn't change, since it's the same shape. But surely the directrices and foci change because the vertices move.

Comment: Sure: you need to rotate the things you found back in the opposite direction.